# How to use SimpleXMLElement Object attributes in PHP, yii2?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to extract some attributes from an XML file. I'm using `simple
xml_load_file()` function to load the xml and saved it in a variable. When I print the variable I get this

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[SERVICE_HTTP_PATH] => https://land-qc.qoda.com
[L10] => https://jd10.loda.com
[TEMP_HTTP_PREVIEW_PATH] => https://land.qoda.com/temp_preview_path
)
```

I want to use `SERVICE_HTTP_PATH` which has the `https://land-qc.qoda.com`. How do I capture the url alone in a variable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `$yourobject->SERVICE_HTTP_PATH`

Comment: I get this `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => https://jdws-qc.qoda.com )` but I want only the url.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your object into array  like this

```
$array= (array) $yourobject;
```

after that you can do this

```
$url = $array['SERVICE_HTTP_PATH'];
```

This should give you your value.